# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I have installed the following, from http://www.django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html

django-nonrel

djangotoolbox

mongodb-engine

after installing i tried to run my program using `python manage.py runserver`

it showing an error like the following,

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1655450>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.7.egg/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

i am using Django 1.5   and python 2.7

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`django-mongodb-engine` expects `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` to be a list for some reason.

You'll have to change your

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   .. apps ..
)
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   .. apps ..
]
```

This is totally `django-mongodb-engine`'s fault and they should feel bad.

They have [this issue](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/150) for seven months and show no concern.

Comment: I have changed my like the way you said, now my INSTALLED_APPS is a list. But now i am getting a different error..it showing that,             TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Can't help without a traceback, sorry. I suggest you create a new question, if you haven't figured it out yet.