# mongoDB and Django TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7

I have installed the following, from [link](http://www.django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html)

```
django-nonrel 

djangotoolbox 

mongodb-engine
```

and i changed my `installed_apps` from

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   .. apps ..
)
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   .. apps ..
]
```

But i am getting an error like the following,

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x12b8450>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.7.egg/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 88, in __init__
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/djangotoolbox/db/base.py", line 28, in __init__

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

i am using **Django 1.5**   and **python 2.7**

thanks in advance

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS should be a tuple... why did you change it to a list?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-non-relational/MNElvfY0Irw

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381603/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-nonrel`is a fork of Django 1.3, so you can't use it with Django 1.5. Try uninstalling Django 1.5.

Comment: I discarded the idea of using mongodb with django since it was not officially supported... My choice has been hard but right, I'm happy :)

Comment: I have uninstalled Django 1.5 and installed 1.3 but now i am facing another issue, ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse

Comment: Uninstall django and run `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5`  OR   remove `LOGGING` from `settings.py`